# How to define a dependency to setup the package before running find_package

Tags: cmake, cpack

That's unusual for a basic CMake, but might be useful for large projects of multiple individual components. Say someone used CPack to create a binary blob accompanied by proper `Find*.cmake` rules. Now we want to automate expansion of this archive *before* the corresponding `find_package` is called. If the package is not outdated, then there is no need to unpack the archive. Given that `find_package` is configure-time, while any custom target is build-time, how could we implement such scenario?

Comment: Not sure that understand the problem. You can use `execute_process` for run commands immediately, at configure time. Placing `execute_process` before `find_package` you may ensure that these commands will be completed before processing of `find_package`.

Comment: You are right, but that would be executed always, not only when archive is outdated?

Comment: Yes, the commands in `execute_process` are executed every time the project is configured. Your question post in its current form doesn't state, that you want *conditional* extracting of the archive. Could you update the question for reflect your **actual** requirements?

Comment: OK, updated question.

Comment: At configure time CMake doesn't use dependency-checking for determine, whether it is needed to perform some action or not. So you need to perform such check manually. It could be, that [file(TIMESTAMP)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/command/file.html#timestamp) would be useful. Alternatively, you may create additional CMake project, which will guide updating the file, and build this project inside `execute_process`.

Comment: It would be much easier to use CPack to produce DEB/RPM/NuGet instead of *blob* and install 'em (**using a real package manager**) before building your project.